# Python - sum of certain numbers in list

Tags: python, list, sum, reverse

Say I have a list (This list can have any amount of numbers):

```
a = [2,5,2,4]
```

I want to reverse that:

```
a[::-1]
```

which gives me `[4,2,5,2]`.
Then I want to achieve the sum of the first number, the sum of the first 2 number, the sum of the first 3 number etc.
So I should get:

```
[4,6,11,13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for loop.

```
>>> m = []              # creates an empty list
>>> j = 0               # Declare a variable and assign 0 to it. This would be used to store the calculated intermediate sum.
>>> for i in a[::-1]:   # iterate over each item in the reversed list. 
        j += i          # For each iteration, add the element with the j value and then assign the result back to the variable j.
        m.append(j)     # Append the content of j to the list m.


>>> m
[4, 6, 11, 13]
```

Comment: using `reversed(a)` instead of making a copy `a[::-1]` is more efficient.